# visual studio for mac - cannot preview android

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I've installed Visual Studio for Mac and started a new Solution. I should be able to preview on the Android screen (see attached) but cannot get it to work. Any ideas?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkvLP.png)

Here's the detail:
This is the error message inside the Android Preview: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.b__31_0 (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.AttributeData a) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions/CodeModelBridge.cs:403 
  at System.Linq.ImmutableArrayExtensions.Any[T] (System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[T] immutableArray, System.Func`2[T,TResult] predicate) [0x00025] in <36486b016d234fca8cd67892bf29c7b5>:0 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.IsActivityType (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol type) [0x00008] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions/CodeModelBridge.cs:403 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.GetAndroidEntityForType (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol type) [0x00001] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions/CodeModelBridge.cs:120 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.b__26_2 (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.INamedTypeSymbol t) [0x00000] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions/CodeModelBridge.cs:311 
  at System.Linq.Utilities+<>c__DisplayClass1_0`1[TSource].<CombinePredicates>b__0 (TSource x) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Utilities.cs:58 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].ToList () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs:737 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/ToCollection.cs:30 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge+<GetCustomComponentsInProject>d__26.MoveNext () [0x00147] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions/CodeModelBridge.cs:308 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject+d__101.MoveNext () [0x00025] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:300 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject+d__102.MoveNext () [0x00020] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:307 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject+d__54.MoveNext () [0x0038a] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/DesignerProject.cs:141 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidDesignerService+d__57.MoveNext () [0x0005a] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Android/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/Xamarin.AndroidDesigner/AndroidDesignerService.cs:464 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.XamarinStudioXamlPreviewerView+<InitializeAndroidDesignerProject>d__65.MoveNext () [0x00122] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.FormsPreviewer.MonoDevelop/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/XamarinStudioXamlPreviewerView.cs:542 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer+d__15.MoveNext () [0x00078] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview/Android/AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:78 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer+d__17.MoveNext () [0x0004b] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview/Android/AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:122 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
  at Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview.AndroidXamlRenderer+d__18.MoveNext () [0x000a0] in /Users/vsts/agent/2.133.3/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.Forms/Xamarin.Designer.Forms.Preview/Android/AndroidXamlRenderer.cs:197

Comment: This is the error message inside the Android Preview:

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was that the Java version I had was 10 and I needed version 8. Then open preferences in VS and tell it where the new version of Java is. That then allowed me to update the SDKs, update VS (restart) and everything works.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html